# Errors setting up Admob with LIBGDX

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, admob

I followed LIBGDX's tutorial on setting up AdMob: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

and my "AndroidLauncher.java" currently looks like this:

```
package com.theashcode.hfcytGame.android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import com.theashcode.hfcytGame.Game;


public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

AdView adView;
View gameView;


@Override public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    // Create the layout
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    // Create the libgdx View
   gameView = initializeForView(new Game(), config );
```

---- Lines causing problems -----

```
    // Create and setup the AdMob view
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "ca-app- pub-000000000000");// Put in your secret key here
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

---- End of Lines causing problems ------

```
    // Add the libgdx view
    layout.addView(gameView);

    // Add the AdMob view
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    // Hook it all up
    setContentView(layout);
}
}
```

As I pointed out I am getting an error on this line

```
// Create and setup the AdMob view
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "ca-app- pub-000000000000");
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

On the first line it says "The Constructor AdView(AndroidLauncher, AdSize, String) is undefined

And on the second line it says

**- "The method loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest) in the type AdView is not applicable for the arguments (com.google.ads.AdRequest)**

**- "The constructor AdRequest() is not visible"**

If anyone could help me I would appreciate it a lot, thanks. I am quite new to libGDX.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with libGDX but with the ad packages you're importing

Don't put google-play-services.jar in the /libs/ folder. Instead, reference the google play services library in your project.

Import the library into your workspace. You'll find it in `sdk/extras/google/`.. if you downloaded via the sdk manager. Then reference by right clicking your project => selecting properties => Android => Add

You then need to make the following changes:

Change:

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "ca-app- pub-000000000000");
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

To

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app- pub-000000000000");
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Within the application tag in your manifest, change:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"/>
```

To:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>`
```

Add:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Don't forget the permissions:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, in the libs folder there's only "google-play-services.jar" and I only have these classes imported now: import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

however I still get the error. Thanks for the help.